# Prove that if $T: V \rightarrow W$ is an application s.t $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$, then T is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Well, I know right that I could find a counterexample to prove that this is false.
Anyone knows one?
Note that $dim(V),\hspace{3.25pt}dim(W)<\infty$

Comment: It's not trivial.  See, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377638/additive-function-t-mathbbr-rightarrow-mathbbr-that-is-not-linear) for the standard sort of counterexample.

Comment: Even in the case $V=W=\mathbb R$ (as vector spaces over $\mathbb R$) $T$ need not be linear.

Comment: I'd edit the question