# Which functions have the property $f(ab)=f(a)+f(b)$?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, functional-equations

I know that the logarithmic functions satisfy this, as
$$\log_x{ab}=\log_x{a}+\log_x{b}$$
but do any other functions satisfy this? Thank you.

I have seen this SE question ([A function that verifies the property $f(ab) = f(a) + f(b)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3450222/a-function-that-verifies-the-property-fab-fa-fb)), but I don't really undertand its notation and it hasn't actually given any examples of other fucntions that satisfy the stated property.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98673/examples-of-functions-where-fab-fafb

Comment: @scoopfaze I don't understand how it gets from $f(e^x e^y)$ to $f(e^x)+f(e^y)$.

Comment: @A-levelStudent $f$ is assumed to be a function that has this property

Comment: @A-levelStudent. Take $a=e^x$ and $b=e^y$ in $f(ab)=f(a)+f(b).$

Answer (score 4):

There are a bunch:  $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ many.  Choose a value for $f(1)$.  That will force a value of $f(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb Q$.

Now choose your favorite irrational number.  (I'm partial to $\sqrt 2$ myself.)  Assign it a value arbitrarily.  That forces a value for any number of the form $a+b \sqrt 2$, where $a, b \in \Bbb Q$.

Now choose another irrational number that's not a (finite) linear combination (over $\Bbb Q$) of $1$ and $\sqrt 2$.  Lather, rinse, repeat.  You'll have $2^{\aleph_0}$ choices to make before you run out of numbers that avoid previous linear combinations, and you can assign a value for each of those choices arbitrarily.