# Discontinuous homomorphism between Lie groups

Tags: geometry, group-theory, continuity, lie-groups, group-homomorphism

I recently began to study Lie group theory and I found the classical result:

> Theorem: Every continuous homomorphism $\varphi: \mathcal{G} \to
>  \mathcal{H}$ of groups is a homomorphism of Lie groups.

I was wondering the following: is the continuity of the homomorphism necessary? I was trying to find a discontinuous homomorphism between Lie groups but I'm unable to do so. There a fairly easy/non exotic example?

Comment: Continuous has two `u`s in it at the end. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Take $G,H$ to be the group of positive reals under multiplication. Taking the logarithm transforms this question into finding a function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ for all real $a,b$ but $f$ is not continuous. This can be done with the Axiom of Choice. See here: [Additive function $T: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is not linear.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377638/additive-function-t-mathbbr-rightarrow-mathbbr-that-is-not-linear).

As for if Choice is necessary to find a counterexample, I would be interested to know as well.

Comment: There are models of ZF where every subset of real numbers is measurable.

Comment: @MoisheKohan certainly for this pair of Lie groups, it is well-known to require choice. But I'm curious if this can be shown for all such pairs.

Comment: It is actually known that for, say, groups of real points of reductive algebraic groups the problem reduces to exotic homomorphisms of coefficient fields.